# How to start two media players at the same time (and let play synchronously)?

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, synchronous

For example: I have two sounds. Both 40 seconds duration. I need to start them at the same time. Here is my method:

```
private void startPlaying() {
        mPlayerDrums = MediaPlayer.create(this, mCurrentDrumResId);
        mPlayerDrums.setLooping(true);

        mPlayerTrack = MediaPlayer.create(this, mCurrentTrackResId);
        mPlayerTrack.setLooping(true);

        if (STATE == STATE_PLAY) {
            mPlayerDrums.start();
            mPlayerTrack.start();
        }

        setPlayersVolume(mSeekbar.getProgress());
    }
```

but sometimes they do not play synchronously. From the logs (every 400ms it displays position of the players):

```
05-03 14:47:01.190: V/wise(23335): drums pos 0 track pos 0
05-03 14:47:01.600: V/wise(23335): drums pos 93 track pos 0
05-03 14:47:02.001: V/wise(23335): drums pos 766 track pos 766
05-03 14:47:02.401: V/wise(23335): drums pos 1138 track pos 1138
05-03 14:47:02.801: V/wise(23335): drums pos 1556 track pos 1509
05-03 14:47:03.202: V/wise(23335): drums pos 1950 track pos 1950
```

Comment: I think u have to set setOnPreparedListener on both media player object and put flag onPrepared()..Don't call play until both flags are true.Haven't checked but u should try.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Just tried - still nothing.

Comment: @Flash I have checked this but sometimes the problem accures

Answer (score 2):

You can use CyclingBarrier to start two players in one time. something like this

```
    CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier = new CyclingBarrier(2);
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
        new StartThread(player).start();
    }

    public class StartThread extends Thread {
        private MediaPlayer player;
        public StartThread(MediaPlayer player) {
            this.player = player;
        }
        @Override
        public void run(){
            cyclingBarrier.await();
            player.start();
        }
    }
```